# Image is not displayed while Posting image on Facebook in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook

I'm trying to post an image on Facebook wall. It's some time working for me, if i'm trying to post the same from another user, i got the post ID but the image is not shown the page.

Could you please help on this?

```
public class fbPostData

{

    public string FbID { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string PostImageURL { get; set; }
    public string TextToRender { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Point TextRenderPonit { get; set; }
}


public bool PostOnFacebookWall(fbPostData _objData_in)

    {
        bool bResult = false;
        try
        {
            if(null != _objData_in)
            {

                //RenderText
                //m_bitmapImage = WriteTextToImage(_objData_in.TextToRender, _objData_in.TextToRender, _objData_in.TextRenderPonit);
                //m_byteDAta = ImageToByte(m_bitmapImage);
                // post the data
                FacebookClient _fbClient = new FacebookClient(_objData_in.AccessToken);
                dynamic _postParams = new ExpandoObject();
                _postParams.message = _objData_in.Message;
                var media = new FacebookMediaObject()
                {
                    ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                    FileName = _objData_in.FbID
                };

                //var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_objData_in.PostImageURL);
                media.SetValue(m_byteDAta);
                var postInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                postInfo.Add("message", _objData_in.Message);
                postInfo.Add("image", media);
                _fbClient.Post("/" + _objData_in.FbID + "/photos", postInfo);

                // return success
                bResult = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return bResult;
    }
```

Comment: um... where is your code?

Comment: I've updated the code.... Can you please look into this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the Post ID from response, that means you successfully uploaded the image. However, it does not upload to your page, which probably is due to incorrect access token used. If you post to page, you have to use **Page Access Token** instead of **User Access Token**. Also, you have to request for `manage_pages` permission, and the user has to grant the request.

Read More about [Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).